# how to display panorama on android

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-image

I got a spherical panorama with 713 * 300 pixels and a cylindrical one with 5026 * 803 pixels. I got these panorama from web.

I use panoramgl to display them. When display the spherical one, it can work, but have one white blank line.The panorama seems has some conjunct error.

When display the cylindrical panorama, it can not work. The screen just gave one black circle.

I use the codes like these.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //PLSphericalPanorama panorama = new PLSphericalPanorama();
    PLCylindricalPanorama panorama = new  PLCylindricalPanorama( );
    panorama.setImage(this.getCurrentGL(), PLImage.imageWithBitmap(PLUtils.getBitmap(this, R.raw.pano)));
    this.setPanorama(panorama);
 }
```

How can I display the panorama? Do I miss something when use panoramaGL?

Answer (score 0):

You should print here the stack-trace...

One reason that that doesn't work is : Because of the size limitation of PanoramaGL it only accept image size's that fall under 1024x1024 try to resize that picture before using it